# Removing Pin Holding Planetary Kitchen Aid Classic Mixer

Tags: repair, appliances

I'm having trouble removing the pin holding the planetary. I need to remove it in order to remove the top of the machine exposing the motor so I can troubleshoot the main problem with my KitchenAid classic. I tapped  the pin with a hammer & drift punch but it  moved very little. I sprayed WD-40 & still no luck. Some of the pin got worn in the process of trying to tap it out. I also damaged a bit of the paint surrounding the pin. How do I remove it while minimizing damage to the machine?
My machine stopped working properly the other day & it could be a worn gear. I wont know the source until I  have access to the motor.
Thanks[image]

[image]m/qHAWL.jpg

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a small appliance. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Answer (score 6):

I spoke to Dan my neighbor on the other side of the fence. Told him my planetary woes and he offered up his **heat gun**, which he swore by for getting troublesome pins out.

I had whacked at the pin with a pin punch and tried WD-40 with no luck. I set the Kitchenaid on its side outside on concrete and heated the pin area for a couple of minutes. Result: The pin popped outed with a few hits on the pin punch just like the the YouTube videos show.

BTW the Kitchenaid chat line folks won't tell you this. They apparently want you to spend more money than a replacement would cost to ship the mixer to them for repairs. If Dan doesn't live close to you, it appears that you can get a **heat gun** delivered by the Amazon devils for about $15. Case closed.

I hope this works for you and save a perfectly good mixer.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this exact problem! Not sure if it still applies to you, but I'm sharing here in case someone else comes across this thread.

I put my whole Kitchenaid mixer into the freezer for several hours (I'm an engineer, and thought that the metals in contact might contract differently when cold...). Once everything was nice and cold, I used the same pin punch and hammer to give it a few hard whacks, and the pin finally moved! A few more hits and it popped right out.

I had previously used a penetrating oil with no success, so I'm not sure if having the oil helped once things were cold or not. Give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at my own mixer, and as @JPhi1618 noted be sure to replace the grease after this repair. The parts supplier I used sold food-safe grease alongside the replacement nylon gear- the old gear got stripped to nothing by the previous owner and plastic was all over the gearbox.

Anyhow, **place the mixer on its side** - That will take the tension off the pin. If hammering it out doesn't work from this side, try the other. Make sure you're using a flat-tipped punch so you don't "Mushroom" the pin. IF it's already been "mushroomed", you'll have to tap from the opposite side. Replace the pin if it's been damaged, or if you're a skilled machinist you could file it back down.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a stuck pin, and after trying the freezing method, the heating method and the WD-40 method, solved the problem in a different way. I used my rubber mallet, and tapped the underside of the planetary up towards the body of the mixer -- just a couple of times and fairly gently. This reduced the tension between the planetary and the steel pin. I was then able to quite easily tap the pin out.